# Open Pay de BBVA y nodejs

Tags: javascript, nodejs, openpay

Hola amigos quiero hacer una consulta y guardarla en una variable en nodejs. Estoy ocupando un servicio de BBVA que me devuelve un json.
Aquí esta la documentación de donde me estoy basando.
https://www.openpay.mx/docs/api/?javascript#listado-de-cargos

Quiero hacer algo así.

```
router.post('/check-conditions/', async (req,res)=>{

    const {id} = req.body;
    const conditions = {};
    const user = await pool.query('select * from USERS_ where id = ? ', [id]);
    const id_client = user[0].id_client;

    const checknsubs = openpay.customers.subscriptions.list(id_client,searchParams,function(error, chargeList) {
        // ...

        return chargeList;
      });
    //checando datos

    console.log(checknsubs);

});
```

Obtengo una respuesta vacía. Alguien puede decirme si no estoy cachando bien la respuesta? tambien trate con `checknsubs[0]`

Comment: Le estás definiendo los `searchParams`? Seguro que el `id_client` viaja con un dato?

Comment: si mi id_client es valido y vi que puedo mandar {searchParams} vacio y me devuelve todo

Answer (score 1):

En esta parte

```
  const checknsubs = openpay.customers.subscriptions.list(id_client,searchParams,function(error, chargeList) {
        // ...

        return chargeList;
      });
```

deberias poner algo como await al metodo openpay.customers, sin embargo aunque lo pongas se ejecutara de la misma manera, ya que esa libreria usa request la cual no es asincrona, por lo que se deberia de editar internamente para que funcione de esa manera, la otra forma mas sencilla y una solucion temporal, es que todo el codigo que quieres que se ejecute lo pongas dentro, en la parte que tiene escrito return chargelist, o si das una respuesta igual;

```
    const checknsubs = openpay.customers.subscriptions.list(id_client,searchParams,function(error, chargeList) {
        // ...

        console.log(chargeList);
        return chargeList;
      });
    //checando datos


});
```

sin embargo igual tardaria en imprimirse en consola, verifica que tambien tengas subscrippciones en tu sandbox, o si no créalas.